# regex only replace dash if there is an empty space in front of it

Tags: regex

I've got a regex expression to replace a dash with a line-break. However, I need to replace the dash only if there is an empty space in front of it.
I've tried this:

```
var txt = str.replace(/^\s-/g,'<br>');
```

However, the dash is also replaced if there is no empty space in front of it. Any suggestions what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is an *an empty space* here? If you mean whitespace, use `.replace(/\s+-/g,'<br>')`

Comment: Why did you place `^` in your regex?

Comment: Which language?

Answer (score 1):

If not to consider possible awful bugs in the regexp implementation, we should come to the conclusion that your string does match the pattern `/^\s-/` if even a dash is placed at the very beginning of a line. How can it happen? Very easy. 
Please note that `\s` stands for a newline (besides other characters). So, if you have a string as "\n-" (newline then dash) it will match the regexp although a dash stands at the beginning of a line (number two) because it also stands exactly one space aside from the beginning of line nuber one.

Thus, try to avoid that a confusing `\s`, use a mere space or `[ \t]` instead.